# What is Storage Usage of XBOX-360 E 4GB/ E 500GB and Play without Internet?

Tags: xbox-360

I am thinking to switch from PC Gaming to xbox 360. But I have two queries before I can go for XBOX-360.

1. I don't have Broadband Connectivity and I would not be getting same for at least 2 years from now. Is it required to have an Internet connection for XBOX. I am not interested to play online or Downloading games from `XBOX-LIVE` rather I will purchase it in CD/DVD etc. Is it Possible ?
2. What is the use of storage in `XBOX-360 4GB` & `XBOX-360 500GB`. If I go for XBOX-360 E 4GB, Is it possible to use USB Drive as storage media. Since I will not use internet in that case should I prefer 4GB or 500GB. I intend to play games like GTA-V and someone told me that It is about 8GB and will not be available if I use 4GB machine.

Please advice.
Thanks :)

Comment: You don't _need_ internet if you are only interested in single player games but you won't be able to download any updates without it.

Comment: @cutypi Could I play games like `wwe2k14` with my friends on same machine. i.e. double player but not multiplayer(players on different machine).

Comment: I have not personally played that game but I would assume that if it is on the same Xbox you would have no issue with it.

Comment: @Raja Wikipedia has a big list of [360 games that support co-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cooperative_games_for_the_Xbox_360), any games in that list that say "*(same screen)*" should allow you to play with friends on the same system without needing broadband. [Co-Optimus is another good source for this](http://www.co-optimus.com/games.php?alltime=true), select Xbox 360 as your system and then select either "Couch Co-Op" or "Split-Screen" to find suitable games.

Answer (score 1):

0) PCMR
1) You can buy games as DVDs and play like that, yes.
2) According to Wikipedia, there is no 500gb model, there are 2 Xbox 360 S models, one at 4 GB and one at 250 GB, but afaik, you can't play some big games like GTA V on 4 GB edition.

Comment: Is there an option that I could use USB storage instead ?

Comment: @Raja On pc, YES. On Xbox, idk.

Comment: @Raja click to the green "accept tick" on the left if this answer helped you.